# React, overriding current state with the original state

Tags: reactjs, overriding, state

I am working on a billing component in a SPA using React. The user can fill out a checkout form and upon payment confirmation I want to reset the current (dirty) state, to the original (clean) state.

I'm using something like this in componentDidMount:

```
this.baseState = this.state;
```

and later when I get my payment confirmation I go ahead and reset the state:

```
this.setState(this.baseState)
```

this works as expected, except for one part small of the state that does not get reset.

That specific part of the state looks like this originally:

```
this.state = {
        billing: {
            coupons: []
        }
}
```

Here it is after being modified:

```
this.state = {
        billing: {
            coupons: ["coupon1", "coupon2"]
        }
}
```

However, when I reset the state, I expect coupons to be an empty array, but somehow the data persists and it remains:

```
coupons: ["coupon1", "coupon2"]
```

Everything else is overridden accordingly, just this part persists. What am I missing?

Comment: By `this.baseState = this.state; ` you are holding the ref of `state` in `baseState`, so when `state` changes `baseState` also changes, bcos both are the same and `this.setState(this.baseState)` is not going to show any difference. try doing `this.setState({ billing: {coupons: ["a1", "a2"] }})` and see.

Comment: Following on from above comment, you shouldn't set object variables equal to each other like that, otherwise you'll get issues where the two variables are actually just references to the same object. So changing one will change both. Use things like `Object.assign` or `Array.slice()` for creating copies of objects and arrays. And be aware of nested object values when doing so (your state is an object, and billing is an object with that). Copying/updating nested objects (like when using `setState()`) may require some additional handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because `this.baseState` will have a reference of state values means `this.state` and `this.baseState` will point to same data.

One solution is put the state values in a function and call that whenever you want the initial values.

Like this:

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = this.getInitialState()
}

getInitialState(){
    return {
        key: value
    }
}
```

Now when you want to reset the state call that function and get the initial state value.

```
this.setState(this.getInitialState())
```

If you want to store the state values in a variable, then deep clone it, Like this (one possible way of deep cloning):

```
this.baseState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state))
```

Comment: Your original function solution would render my state immutable, am I right?

Comment: However, your deep copy solution worked like a charm. You are a gentleman and a scholar.

Answer (score 0):

It was rightly pointed out that the spread operator does not do a deep copy. So for a large state we would need to write a custom function. This should work for a simple state:

```
this.baseCoupons=[...this.state.billing.coupons]


this.setState({billing:{coupons:[...this.baseCoupons]}})
```

Comment: As I know, the **spread operator/syntax** doesn't support deep clone. Hence ref of `coupons` array in state will be in `baseState`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can confirm that this does not create a deep copy and the reference to the array in this.state is still present.

Comment: Please try this